# Does milk sold in a store with good product turnover lose a significant amount of Vitamin B2 from light exposure?

Tags: marketing, milk, vitamins, light

Anchor New Zealand has just released a milk bottle with a black plastic layer to protect the milk from exposure to light, and thus from loss of "taste and goodness". Their chart:
[image]
from [their website](http://www.anchor.co.nz/#lightproof/lib-goodness) specifically shows test results relating to vitamin B2 loss.

However, their testing is based on 2000 Lux of light, which apparently [is excessive for a supermarket](http://www.toplightco.com/acatalog/How_Much_Light_Do_I_need_.html). Secondly, milk is unlikely to be exposed to the full brightness of light for very long unless it's perhaps a variety of milk that doesn't sell quickly.

**How much vitamin B2 is lost under typical conditions (ie a high-turnover product, quickly put into the fridge at home)? Has anyone actually measured the level of vitamin B2 remaining after, say, half the milk has been consumed under normal circumstances?**

I note that they clearly label their graph as "an example", which is probably intended to avoid law suits while still aiming for an emotional response from the consumer.

Comment: in my country milk is mostly sold in opaque containers, then again most of it's [ultra-high-temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high-temperature_processing) treated